# JSON string to model / HashMap/ Dictionary in C#

Tags: c#, json, dictionary, hashmap

I have JSON:

```
{
"One": [
{
  "ID": 1,
  "name": "s"
},
{
  "categoryID": 2,
  "name": "c"
}
],
"Two": [
{
  "ID": 3,
  "name": "l"
}
],
"Three": [
{
  "ID": 8,
  "name": "s&P"
},
{
  "ID": 52,
  "name": "BB"
}
]
}
```

I want to:

1. Take this JSON to any object(like JObject)
2. Filter the JSON on different conditions(like name start with s, etc
3. Return this JSON to client

Things I have tried:
1. Creating models:

```
class Model
{
public int Id;
public string name;
}
class MainModel
{
public string mainName;
public List<Model> categories;
}
```

And use these model to:

```
List<MainModel> m = json_serializer.DeserializeObject(jsonString);
```

2. I tried to Dictionary also but getting unable to cast exception.

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try `Dictionary<string, List<Model>>`?

Comment: `var jObj = JObject.Parse(jsonString);` Now you have more than a dictionary. http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm

Comment: I have tried Dictionary: Dictionary<string, List<Model>> dct = (Dictionary <string, List< Model >>) json_serializer.DeserializeObject(json); I am getting  Invalid cast exception

Comment: Obviously you will get invalid cast exception.Your model is not consistent with the JSON

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following will allow you to deserialize your JSON to a Dictionary and filter on it. This uses Newtonsoft.Json Nuget package, but that's fairly common. Code posted below. Working example found here [.Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/QJGOB1).

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;


public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var json = "{\"One\": [{  \"ID\": 1,  \"name\": \"s\"},{  \"categoryID\": 2,  \"name\": \"c\"}],\"Two\": [{  \"ID\": 3,  \"name\": \"l\"}],\"Three\": [{  \"ID\": 8,  \"name\": \"s&P\"},{  \"ID\": 52,  \"name\": \"BB\"}]}";      
        var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, List<Model>>>(json);

        Console.WriteLine(deserialized["One"][0].name);

        Console.WriteLine("Filter to starts with s");
        var filtered = deserialized.SelectMany(item => item.Value).Where(innerItem => innerItem.name.StartsWith("s"));
        foreach(var item in filtered){
            Console.WriteLine(item.name);   
        }

    }

    public class Model{
        public int ID {get;set;}
        public string name {get;set;}
        public int categoryID {get;set;}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## I have written this code assuming that:

- `One`, `Two` and  `Three` are a `MainCategory` -which is seralized as `JProperty` from a `KeyValuePair<string name, List<SubCategory> values>`. Long type name, eh? Add the following if you want to use the result dictionary often:

  ```
  using MainCategories = System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, System.Collections.Generic.List<JsonDeSerializtionTest.SubCategory>>;
  ```
- `categoryID` and `ID` are properties that descibe an `Id` and can not co-exist on the same `SubCategory` but do change the type of `SubCategory`.

### 1. Create the `SubCategory` class:

```
public class SubCategory
{
    [JsonIgnore]
    public DataTypes DataType { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public string Parent { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("ID")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("categoryID")]
    public int CategoryId => Id;

    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public bool ShouldSerializeId()
    {
        return DataType == DataTypes.Id;
    }

    public bool ShouldSerializeCategoryId()
    {
        return DataType == DataTypes.CategoryId;
    }

}
```

### 2. Create the `Deserialize(string json)` function:

```
private static MainCategories Deserialize(string json)
{
    Dictionary<string, List < SubCategory >> jsonBody = new Dictionary<string, List<SubCategory>>();

    JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(json);
    // the outer object {one...two..}

    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, JToken> jMainCategory in jObject)
    {
        // jMainCategory => "one": [{...}, {...}]
        string key = jMainCategory.Key;
        List<SubCategory> values = new List<SubCategory>();
        foreach (JObject jSubCategory in jMainCategory.Value)
        {
            //jsubCategory => {"name" : ..., "ID": ... }
            SubCategory subCategory = new SubCategory();

            JToken idProperty;
            if (jSubCategory.TryGetValue("ID", out idProperty))
            {
                subCategory.DataType = DataTypes.Id;
                subCategory.Id = idProperty.Value<int>();
            }
            else
            {
                subCategory.DataType = DataTypes.CategoryId;
                subCategory.Id = jSubCategory["categoryID"].Value<int>();
            }

            subCategory.Name = jSubCategory["name"].Value<string>();
            subCategory.Parent = key;
            // subCategory.AnotherProperty = jSubCategory["anotherproperty"].Value<type>();

            values.Add(subCategory);
        }
        jsonBody.Add(key, values);
    }
    return jsonBody;
}
```

### 3. Use the function to get a `Dictionary<string, List<SubCategory>>` which you can use for sorting and filtering. Example:

```
public static MainCategories WhereNameStartsWith(this MainCategories jsonBody, string str)
{
    MainCategories result = new MainCategories();
    //if you want to keep the result json structure `as is` return a MainCategories object

    foreach (var subCategory in jsonBody.SelectMany(mainCategory => mainCategory.Value).Where(subCategory => subCategory.Name.StartsWith(str)))
    {
        if(result.ContainsKey(subCategory.Parent))
            result[subCategory.Parent].Add(subCategory);
        else
            result.Add(subCategory.Parent, new List<SubCategory> {subCategory});
    }
    // if you just want the subcategories matching the condition create a WhereListNameStartsWith method
    // where `result` is a list of subcategories matching the condition
    return  result;
}
```

### Upside:

- No playing around with `NewtonSoft` JsonConverter or ContractResolvers.
- The ability to use LINQ to easily sort `Name` AND `CategoryId`/`Id` which have the same value but make a different `SubCategory.DataType`:

  ```
  foreach (var subCategory in jsonBody.SelectMany(mainCategory => mainCategory.Value).Where(subCategory => subCategory.DataType == DataTypes.CategoryId))
  ```
- You can easily serialize the JSON back to string representation. Example:

  ```
  string jsonIn ="{\"One\":[{\"ID\":1,\"name\":\"s\"}," +
                               "{\"categoryID\":2,\"name\":\"c\"}]," +
                  "\"Two\":[{\"ID\":3,\"name\":\"l\"}]," +
                  "\"Three\":[{\"ID\":8,\"name\":\"s&P\"}," +
                                "{\"ID\":52,\"name\":\"BB\"}]}";
  MainCategories desrializedJson = Deserialize(jsonIn);
  MainCategories filtered = desrializedJson.WhereNameStartsWith("s");
  string jsonOut = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(desrializedJson, Formatting.None);
  Debug.Assert(jsonOut == jsonIn); //true
  ```
- Removes the need for null checking when accessing `Id`/`CategoryId`.
- My favorite: using C# syntax for property names.

### Downside:

- I don't know. This is a paste and forget soltuion :P

  Probably a harder time when changing your JSON structure (although I might  argue it would make things much easier for you)

## Notes:

- `Parent` is optional and is used to make things easier when using LINQ
- `DataTypes` is an enum which is used to determine wether `ID` or `categoryID` was found if you want such information and also to serialize the proper property (identical two way convertion)

  ```
  public enum DataTypes
  {
      Id,
      CategoryId
  };
  ```